# Get radio button label from different radio button groups and append to division

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, radio-button

There are 3 radio button groups for user to select.
Division '#targetOption' will get whenever the user checked radio button label to be displayed. Below my code which is able to get the first checked radio button.

Example if user click on the first radio button group, #targetOption will show A. Then if user click on the second radio button group, #targetOption will show A B.

```
<div id="options">
    <div class="form-group required"> 
        <div class="radio"> 
            <label> <input type="radio" value="a">
            A   
            </label> 
        </div>
        <div class="radio"> 
            <label> <input type="radio" value="b">
            B   
            </label> 
        </div>
        <div class="radio"> 
            <label> <input type="radio" value="c">
            C   
            </label> 
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group required"> 
        <div class="radio"> 
            <label> <input type="radio" value="d">
            D   
            </label> 
        </div>
        <div class="radio"> 
            <label> <input type="radio" value="e">
            E  
            </label> 
        </div>
        <div class="radio"> 
            <label> <input type="radio" value="f">
            F   
            </label> 
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group required"> 
        <div class="radio"> 
            <label> <input type="radio" value="g">
            G   
            </label> 
        </div>
        <div class="radio"> 
            <label> <input type="radio" value="h">
            H   
            </label> 
        </div>
        <div class="radio"> 
            <label> <input type="radio" value="i">
            I   
            </label> 
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>  
    <div id="targetID"></div>

        $('#options').click(function() {
                        $('#targetID').html('');

                        $("input[type='radio']:checked").each(function() {
                          var optiontext = $(this).parent().text();
                          console.log(optiontext);
                         $('#targetID').html(optiontext);
                        });


                      });
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('#targetID').html(optiontext);` set `#targetID` to the current radio value in the loop instead of appending it to `#targetID`.

Use `$('#targetID').html($('#targetID').html() + optiontext);` instead.

Or you can create an array to store the checked values and update `#targetID` later

Comment: Thanks you, it works! How am I going to mark this as solution? I am new in stackoverflow